# Send data from dynamically created fields to controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, controller

I am currently working on a .NET Core project and I have a form that contains different fields. Some are fields that can be dynamically generated by pressing a button using jQuery/Javascript

```js
$(function() {

  $(".addRow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var template = $("#items").find(".itemRow").first();
    var newRow = template.clone();
    newRow.find("input.formfield").val("");
    $("#items").append(newRow);

  });

  // I have tried adding this set of Javascript code to pass data to the `Controller` when I press the button Submit, but it doesn't work..

  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var url = _this.closest("form").attr("action");

    var rows = [];
    var items = $(".itemRow");

    $.each(items, function(i, item) {
      var tbOne = $(item).find("input[name='tbOne']").val();
      var tbTwo = $(item).find("input[name='tbTwo']").val();

      var row = {
        Test1: tbOne,
        Test2: tbTwo
      };
      rows.push(row);
    });

    //Let's post to server
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(rows),
        contentType: "application/json"
      })
      .done(function(result) {
        //do something with the result
      })

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Insert">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <label>Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" asp-for="name" name="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <label>Age</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" asp-for="age" name="Age" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="items">
    <div class="itemRow">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <label>Tb One</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <input type="text" asp-for="tbOne" name="tbOne" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <label>Tb Two</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <input type="text" asp-for="tbTwo" name="tbTwo" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <button type="button" class="addRow">Add Row</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Insert(IEnumerable<Model> model)
{
      foreach (var item in model)
      {
          // to do here
      }
}
```

I hope someone can provide me with advice on how I can further improve this code to successfully obtain data from the dynamically generated fields.

Comment: You do not have anything with ID addrow. The button you DO have is inside the itemrow so it will stop working if you use ID which needs to be unique

Comment: @mplungjan Hi, my apologies for the careless mistakes. I have updated my codes.

Comment: See my answer. You need `$("#items").on("click",".addRow", function(e) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a class for the addrow button and delegate or move it outside the itemRow
2. Do not stringify the data, the ajax will do that for you

```js
$(function() {

  $("#items").on("click",".addRow", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var template = $("#items").find(".itemRow").first();
    var newRow = template.clone();
    newRow.find("input.formfield").val("");
    $("#items").append(newRow);

  });

  // I have tried adding this set of Javascript code to pass data to the `Controller` when I press the button Submit, but it doesn't work..

  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = $(this);
    var url = _this.closest("form").attr("action");

    var rows = [];
    var items = $(".itemRow");

    $.each(items, function(i, item) {
      var tbOne = $(item).find("input[name='tbOne']").val();
      var tbTwo = $(item).find("input[name='tbTwo']").val();

      var row = {
        Test1: tbOne,
        Test2: tbTwo
      };
      rows.push(row);
    });

    //Let's post to server
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: rows,
        contentType: "application/json"
      })
      .done(function(result) {
        //do something with the result
      })

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Insert">
  <div id="items">
    <div class="itemRow">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" asp-for="name" name="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" asp-for="age" name="Age" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" asp-for="tbOne" name="tbOne" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" asp-for="tbTwo" name="tbTwo" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <button class="addRow" type="button">Add Row</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: My concern is not on generating the fields dynamically. I can't pass the values of the generated fields to my controller...

Comment: Ok, that would be another question. Right now you at least have more than one row. Perhaps ask an ASP question if a JSON string of  `[  { "Test1": "tbOne", "Test2": 
 "tbTwo" },{ "Test1": "tbOne", "Test2": "tbTwo" }]` would be read by `public IActionResult Insert(IEnumberable<Model> model){ foreach (var item in model){ ... } }`

Comment: In a new post? Or in the current question?

Comment: New post. It can be simplified to just show an example of the ACTUAL  JSON you are sending and how to parse it